# Unable to send mails using PHP

Tags: php, html, email, wampserver

I am trying to send mails using php. I am using wampserver2.2 . And my php version is 5.4.3

Here is the code I tried:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $YourName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['YourName']);
     $From = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
     $Subject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Subject']);
     $Message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
     $myEmailAdr = "umvss01@gmail.com";

        if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z]+[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]+$/', $From))
        {
             $headers = 'From: '.$From."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$From;
             $Message = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $Message);

             try
             {
                  ini_set("SMTP","ssl:smtp.gmail.com" );
                  ini_set("smtp_port","465");
                  $send = mail($myEmailAdr, $Subject, $Message, $headers ); // line 24
             }
             catch(PDOException $e)
             {
                  $error = $e->getMessage();
                  echo $error;
             }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "Error in Mail Address Format";
        }
    }
?>
```

The problem is I am getting the following error when I try to use it. Line 24 means the mail function.

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "ssl:smtp.gmail.com" port 465, verify your "SMTP"
>   and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in
>   C:\wamp\www\UMVSS_Website\ContactScript.php on line 24

Comment: Neither `ini_set` or `mail` throw a `PDOException`

Answer (score 2):

The PHP `mail()` function doesn't use authentication to the SMTP server, which generally results in an error when connecting to public servers like the one you are trying to connect to. You might want use a library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) which you can autheticate with.

Answer (score 1):

So, GMail requires SMTP authentication. Mail does not provide that interface.

Check out PHPMailer. Here is an [example for connecting to GMail](https://raw.github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/master/examples/gmail.phps)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>PHPMailer - GMail SMTP test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../class.phpmailer.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port       = 587;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username   = "username@gmail.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->SetFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->AddReplyTo('replyto@example.com','First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->AddAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded, convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif');

//Send the message, check for errors
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sometimes answering questions on SO is like an arms race ;)

Comment: Which doesn't work too well when focusing on sipping wine and smoking cigarettes hehe. Great answer anyhow :)

Comment: I used the phpmailer. but it didnt work. it gives me an error. This is the error 

"Message body empty Mailer Error: Message body empty"

Comment: Try adding your body: `$mail->Body=$body;`

Comment: Finally i got it correct. I add $mail->MsgHTML($Message); code instead of $mail->AltBody = $Message; This worked for me

Comment: Great job! It's a nice library